# Send form information to another page and submit that form?

Tags: wordpress, forms, hyperlink, navigation, submission

So here's my dilemma...

I'm creating a site for a client using Wordpress where users can search for members based on member categories. For example, there's a Music Category, with multiple music subcategories.

When you hover over the Music navigation bar, there will be the subcategories. If you click on the subcategory it SHOULD search for members that have that subcategory.

The members search page is its own page with a form on it (I'm using Buddypress for anyone who knows what that is).

Is there a way that I can send data to that form and submit it via the navigation link?

Or am I stuck creating a page for each subcategory with its own members loop??

Thanks for the help in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

If the form submits with a GET request, you can easily forge the corresponding URLs and associate them to the links.

If POST is required, you could change the references to $_POST into $_REQUEST and then create the links.

Comment: I just looked at the form, the method is "POST". Could you walk me through how I would change the references or point me to a good resource?

You can also take a look at the form here: http://your-developmentsite.com/ishocase/members/